# Whats the proper way to preprocess field collection items to add first and last class names?

Tags: theming, entities

How to add `'first'` and `'last'` class names in addtion to `'odd'`/ `'even'` for field collection items in preprocess functions?

Comment: untested: http://dropbucket.org/node/764

Comment: Yepp, have a look inside `hook_preprocess_field(&$vars)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You would normally do this in MYTHEME_preprocess_field_collection_item(), but field collection items don't have their own preprocess. Fortunately, they're entities, so you can use entity preprocess to create your own field collection preprocess function:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_entity().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_entity(&$variables, $hook) {
  $function = 'MYTHEME_preprocess_' . $variables['entity_type'];
  if (function_exists($function)) {
    $function($variables, $hook);
  }
}

/**
 * Field Collection-specific implementation of template_preprocess_entity().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field_collection_item(&$variables) {
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'your-class-here';
  // Plus whatever other preprocessing you want to do.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Drupal 8** the preprocess function exists without having to add one:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_field_collection_item().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_field_collection_item(array &$vars, $hook) {
  //dpm($vars);
}
```